# How to transform a comma-separated string to line-break-separated string?

Tags: c#, string, data-transform

I have a comma-separated string. How can I convert it into line-break-separated format. My string looks like this:

```
red,yellow,green,orange,pink,black,white
```

And needs to be formatted to in this way:

```
red
yellow
green
orange
pink
black
white
```

Here is my code:

```
public static string getcolours()
{
    List<string> colours = new List<string>();
    DBClass db = new DBClass();
    DataTable allcolours = new DataTable();
    allcolours = db.GetTableSP("kt_getcolors");
    for (int i = 0; i < allcolours.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string s = allcolours.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
        string missingpath = "images/color/" + s + ".jpg";
        if (!FileExists(missingpath))
        {
            colours.Add(s);

        }
    }
    string res = string.Join(", ", colours);

    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"F:\test.txt", true))
    {

        file.WriteLine(res);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't string join, just writeline the colors and next return with join on \n

```
public static string getcolours()
{
    List<string> colours = new List<string>();
    DBClass db = new DBClass();
    DataTable allcolours = new DataTable();
    allcolours = db.GetTableSP("kt_getcolors");
    for (int i = 0; i < allcolours.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string s = allcolours.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
        string missingpath = "images/color/" + s + ".jpg";
        if (!FileExists(missingpath))
        {
            colours.Add(s);
        }
    }
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"F:\test.txt", true))
    {
        foreach(string color in colours)
        {
            file.WriteLine(color);
        }
    }
    return string.Join("\n", colours);;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
res = res.Replace(',','\n');
```

This should work.

Answer (score 4):

you can try:

```
string colours = "red,yellow,green,orange,pink,black,white";
string res = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, colours.Split(','));
```

Or much simpler version would be:

```
string res2 = colours.Replace(",", Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "red,yellow,green,orange,pink,black,white";
var r = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, s.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```